# How to reverse a singly linked list recursively without modifying the pointers?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, linked-list

Recently I had an interview and the interviewer asked me to reverse a singly linked list without modifying the pointers(change the values only).
At the beginning I came up with a solution using a stack. He said that was OK and wanted me to do it recursively. Then I gave him a O(n^2) solution. But he said he needs a O(n) solution.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Hint: the recursive version should  swap two values after the recursive call, and return something that would tell the caller what to do.

Comment: Could you please give me a pseudocode here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode

```
reverse (list):
 reverse2 (list, list)

reverse2 (a, b):
 if b != nil:
  a = reverse2 (a, b.next)
  if a != nil:
   swap (a.data, b.data)
   if a == b || a.next == b:
    # we've reached the middle of the list, tell the caller to stop
    return nil
   else:
    return a.next
  else:
   # the recursive step has returned nil, they don't want us to do anything
   return nil
 else:
  # we've reached the end of the list, start working!
  return a
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of doing it is recursing to the end accumulating the values in another list as you resurse to the end, then on the way out of the recursion writing the values back starting with the 1st value in the list. It would be O(2n). It's not much different from using a stack...

Comment: Yeah but he doesn't want me to use an additional structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = { a => b => c => d }

def recursive(acc, x)
  if !x
    return acc
  end
  acc.preprend(x)

  return recursive(acc, x.next)
end

result = recursive([], list.first)
```

So first call is `recursive([], a)`. `result` is now `[a]`.

Second call is `recursive([a], b)`. `result` turns into `[b, a]`.

Third call is `recursive([b, a], c)`. `result` is `[c, b, a]`.

Fourth call is `recursive([c, b, a], d)`, and `result` `[d, c, b, a]`.

Fifth call gets caught by the `if !x`.

Tell your interviewer you need an additional structure, like someone else said above.

Comment: No I can't use an additional structure. I think what he wants me to do is to rewrite the value in the recursion process. Not to return a new linked list.